# Mel-spectrogram vs MFCC for Automatic Speech Recognition

Tags: conv-neural-network, speech-recognition, spectrogram, mfcc

I am trying to do Automatic Speech Recognition using CNN. For the feature extraction I am using MFCC. I have read many articles, some of them say with lot of data and classifiers like CNN, mel spectorgram are better while others say MFCC is better.

So my question is which is better for Automatic Speech Recognition: mel spectrogram or MFCC and why?